# Get n elements of list having the highest property

Tags: haskell, genetic-algorithm

I'm new to Haskell and trying to implement some genetic algorithms.
Currently I fail with the selection of the n best element of a list of individuals (where each individual is a list for itself.
An individual is created as follows:

```
ind1 :: [Int]
ind1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
ind2 :: [Int]
ind2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The appropriate population consists of a list of those individuals:

```
pop :: [[Int]]
pop = [ind1, ind2]
```

What I want to achieve is to get the best n individuals of the population, where the "best" is determined by the sum of its elements, e.g.,

```
> sum ind1
7
> sum ind2
0
```

I started creating a function for creating tuples with individual and its quality:

```
f x = [(ind, sum ind) | ind <- x]
```

so at least I got something like this:

```
[([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 7), ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0)]
```

How do I get from here to the expected result? I do not even manage to get the "fst" of the tuple where "snd == max".
I started with recursive approaches as seen in different topics, but unfortunately without reasonable result.
Any suggestions, probably also where to read?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best choice here is to use `sortBy` from `Data.List`:

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The `sortBy` function is higher order, so it takes a function as one of its arguments.  The function it needs is one that takes two elements and returns a `Ordering` value (`LT`, `EQ` or `GT`).  You can write your own custom comparison function, but the `Data.Ord` module has `comparing`, which exists to help with writing these comparison functions:

```
comparing :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> Ordering)
```

Hopefully you can see how `comparing` pairs with `sortBy`, you pass it a function to convert your type to a known comparable type, and then you have a function of the right type to pass to `sortBy`.  So in practice you can do

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

-- Some types to make things more readable
type Individual = [Int]
type Fitness = Int

-- Here's our fitness function (change as needed)
fitness :: Individual -> Fitness
fitness = sum

-- Redefining so it can be used with `map`
f :: Individual -> (Individual, Fitness)
f ind = (ind, fitness ind)

-- If you do want to see the fitness of the top n individuals
solution1 :: Int -> [Individual] -> [(Individual, Fitness)]
solution1 n inds = take n $ sortBy (flip $ comparing snd) $ map f inds

-- If you just want the top n individuals
solution2 :: Int -> [Individual] -> [Individual]
solution2 n inds = take n $ sortBy (flip $ comparing fitness) inds
```

The `flip` in the arguments to `sortBy` forces the sort to be descending instead of the default ascending, so the first `n` values returned from `sortBy` will be the `n` values with the highest fitness in descending order.  If you wanted to try out different fitness functions then you could do something like

```
fittestBy :: (Individual -> Fitness) -> Int -> [Individual] -> [Individual]
fittestBy fit n = take n . sortBy (flip $ comparing fit)
```

Then you'd have

```
solution2 = fittestBy sum
```

But you could also have

```
solution3 = fittestBy product
```

if you wanted to change your fitness function to be the product rather than the sum.

Comment: Works as expected, perfect explanation even for a Haskell beginner like me (even having clean coding best practices!) Thank you!

Comment: What is the complexity of `solution1` and `solution2`? I suppose it is `m * log(m)` (where `m` is the total number of the individuals) because of the sorting. However, if we need only top `n` fittest individuals, we can solve it in `m * log(n)`, cannot we? Or Haskell is doing the optimization under the hood because of its laziness?

Answer (score 5):

Use [sortBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) and [on](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on).

```
> take 2 $ sortBy (flip compare `on` sum) [[1,2],[0,4],[1,1]]
[[0,4],[1,2]]
```

Comment: This solution works as well but the other answer offers more information. Thank you very much!